# the nvapi NvAPI_GPU_GetDynamicPstatesInfoEx returns NVAPI_ERROR, why?

Tags: windows, nvapi

I don't know why this api returns error,  the graphics card type is "GeForce GTX 1050 Ti"

```
NvAPI_Status nvapiStatus = NVAPI_OK;
if ((nvapiStatus = NvAPI_Initialize()) != NVAPI_OK)
{
    return 1;
}
NvPhysicalGpuHandle handles[NVAPI_MAX_PHYSICAL_GPUS];
NvU32 count = 0;
nvapiStatus = NvAPI_EnumPhysicalGPUs(handles, &count);
NV_GPU_DYNAMIC_PSTATES_INFO_EX info{};
info.version = NV_GPU_DYNAMIC_PSTATES_INFO_EX_VER;
if (nvapiStatus == NVAPI_OK && count == 1)
{
    double dGPUUtilization = 0.0;
    nvapiStatus = NvAPI_GPU_GetDynamicPstatesInfoEx(handles[0], &info);
    if (nvapiStatus == NVAPI_OK)
    {
        if (info.utilization[0].bIsPresent)
        {
            dGPUUtilization = info.utilization[0].percentage;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found one reason which will cause this error:  no process is using this graphic card